# scala slick does not persist data

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have the following code which does not work ... not work means in this case it does not persis in database....

DTO / DAO

```
  def createChangelogEntry(changeLog: ChangelogModel): Future[ChangelogModel] = {
    println("..........................................")
    println(changeLog)

    val entry =
      (changelogs returning changelogs.map(_.id)
        into ((log,id) => log.copy(id=Some(id)))
        ) += ChangelogModel(None, changeLog.createdat, changeLog.text)

    db.run(entry)
  }
```

what could be the problem in this case? match on the model works fine ...

UUpdate:

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Changelog (
  id BIGINT(255) NOT NULL,
  createdat DATETIME NOT NULL,
  text text NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My Model:

```
package models

import java.sql.Date

import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json, Writes}

/**
  * Created by Felix Hohlwegler on 08.06.2017.
  */
case class ChangelogModel(
                           id: Option[Int] = None,
                           createdat: String,
                           text: String
                         )

object ChangelogModel {
  implicit val changelogFormat = Json.format[ChangelogModel]
}
```

Controller Function:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}

import dto.changelogDTO
import models.{ChangelogModel, ProcessTemplatesModel}
import play.api.libs.json.{JsError, JsSuccess, Json}
import play.api.mvc.{Action, AnyContent, Controller, Request}

import scala.concurrent.Future

/**
  * Created by Felix Hohlwegler on 08.06.2017.
  */
@Singleton
class Changelogs @Inject()(changelogDTO: changelogDTO) extends Controller {

  def createChangelogEntry = Action { implicit request =>
    request.body.asJson.map(_.validate[ChangelogModel] match {
      case JsSuccess(process, _) =>
        changelogDTO.createChangelogEntry(process)
      case err@JsError(_) => BadRequest("TEST")
      case _ => BadRequest("fail to create Counter")
    }).getOrElse(BadRequest("Failure tu create Counter"))
    Ok("s")
  }
}
```

Comment: and no exceptions are being thrown?

Comment: no absolute nothing looks like it works perfekt ... but database is empty ...

Comment: Can you post your configuration?

Comment: updatetd code above

Comment: In your first case statement in your controller function you are not waiting for your `changelogDTO.createChangelogEntry` to complete

Comment: can you please give me an example how it should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you are not waiting for your insert to complete from your controller:

```
// Problem
case JsSuccess(process, _) => changelogDTO.createChangelogEntry(process)
```

You should be mapping on the future and returning its result asynchronously like this:

```
// Do this
case JsSuccess(process, _) => changelogDTO.createChangelogEntry(process).map(model => Ok(Json.toJson(model))
```

However this will mean that you will need all of the other cases to return futures too, and you will have to change the resulting action to by async.  This is how I would do it:

```
def createChangelogEntry = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
  request.body.validate[ChangelogModel].fold(
    errors => Future(BadRequest(JsError.toJson(errors))),
    changelogModel => changelogDTO.createChangelogEntry(changelogModel).map(model => Ok(Json.toJson(model))
  )
}
```

In the meantime you might find it easier to debug by just wrapping your current insert in an `Await.result` like this:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

case JsSuccess(process, _) => 
  val model = Await.result(changelogDTO.createChangelogEntry(process), 5 seconds)
  Ok("We inserted the thing")
```

Comment: Await is old style not recomended to use .... 

have lots of other inserts that work perfekt without await ...

Comment: "In the meantime you might find it easier to **debug** by just wrapping your current insert in an Await"

Comment: is there no other solution?

Comment: All of the branches of your code need to have a common return type.  If one branch of your code is returning a `Future` then you will have to make all of the other branches return futures as well.  In your original controller function you are not getting a compiler warning because you put `Ok("s")` on the end and that will be the return, meanwhile you are trying to call your DAO function but completely ignoring the asynchronous result

Comment: I made one more edit and changed how I would implement your controller function

Comment: But with await again .. isn't there a way without await

Comment: Yes you can do it without await, like I have shown in my example, you have to make the whole action asynchronous

Comment: When I use your example I got this eror `Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext. You might pass
[error] an (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) parameter to your method
[error] or import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global.
[error]       changelogModel => changelogDTO.createChangelogEntry(changelogModel).map(model => Ok(Json.toJson(model))`

Comment: The error tells you exactly how to fix it `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`

Comment: thanks at all, I've done it with await and got the errors (SQL problems) solved it and removed await. thanks